# Prolog : Comparing numbers in a list

Tags: list, prolog, compare, comparison

I have this block of numbers:

```
num(1).
num(-2).
num(5).
num(50).
num(-3).
num(87).
```

I'm supposed to make a function that given a number it is supposed to check if that number is the smallest of that "list" of numbers given above.

ex:

```
not_smallest(5).
true.

not_smallest(X).
X = 1 ;
X = -2 ;
X = 5 ;
X = 50 ;
X = 87.
```

What i thought was making a list with the above block of numbers , and comparing a given number to all elements of the list.
But whenever i try to load the .pl doc i get this error:

```
Syntax error: Operator expected
```

what i have done so far is this:

```
%increments the index of a List

incr(X, X1) :-
    X1 is X + 1.

%L-list containing "list" of numbers, N - elements of that "list",
I-index , C-number X is going to be compared to, X- number to compare.

 nao_menor(X) :-
    findall(N, num(N), L),
    num(X),
    I is 0,
    nth0(I, L, C),
    X =< C,
    incr(I,I).
```

Comment: The `%` character specifies a comment line (cannot have newlines), so you should add % at the start of the line `'I-index....'` or put those two lines in a single one

Comment: Also your `nao_menor/1` procedure won't work as you expect. (e.g. `incr(I,I)` will always fail)

Comment: I just added the % now to specify what the variables were,  it's not in the original code but thank-you for that heads up.

Comment: Why will the incr (I, I) allways fail?

Comment: What is the meaning of `incr(I,I)`?

Comment: It increments the index,  so I can compare X to all elements of the list

Comment: I see what you are getting at: you are trying to construct some kind of loop between `I is 0` and `incr(I,I)`... it will not work that way.

Comment: Yes that was the idea.  I started with value 0, X was compared the the first element to the list. Then I was incremented 1 and become 1, X was compared to the second element,  and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we go:

```
not_smallest(N) :-
   num(N),
   \+ \+ (num(M), M < N).
```

Sample queries as given by the OP:

```
?- not_smallest(5).
true.

?- not_smallest(X).
  X =  1
; X = -2
; X =  5
; X = 50
; X = 87.
```

Comment: Is it impossible to do the way I was trying to do it?

Comment: @eXistanCe. I don't quite get what you are trying to do with the `findall` followed by `nth0`. `findall` does not sort, `setof` OTOH does...

Comment: The idea was not to sort the values,  it was simply to put them in a list,  thus the findall and then compare any value to the ones stored in the list. Return true if he wasn't smaller than any of the list elements and false if it was